# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7, common fixes not resolving

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know this is a really common question, and I'll list what I've tried here but I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out why I can't import a third party SDK in Xcode.  Common fixes suggested in other threads has not worked.

I'm getting the error output listed below, and I have tried:

1. Adding the correct libraries in the *Link Binary With Librarie*s section of the Build Phases
2. I copied the *DoubleControlSDK.framework* file to the default Library Search Path in *Build Settings*
3. I added the .m files to *Build Phases > Compile Source*s
4. I yelled really loud at the screen, and threatened to disassemble the computer if it didn't link the damn files.

No idea what else to try.  I'm hoping maybe there's something in the error output that I'm not noticing.  Need to go outside for a while

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DoubleControlSDK
"_EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
  -[DRDouble init] in DoubleControlSDK
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DoubleControlSDK
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZBarReaderView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in EmbedReaderAppDelegate.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simply drag and drop the .framework file to the project tree? Or, drag to the 'frameworks' in the project settings (or by clicking '+').

Comment: Provide screenshot of your frameworks in Xcode (Linked Frameworks and Libraries).

Comment: Added the pic of Libraries and Frameworks to OP.  And yeah, I tried dragging it in, and I've made copies of the .framework at several locations, thinking that maybe it wasn't seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Phillip Mills' answer helped, I discovered that the real reason for all these crazy problems I've been having is that my ZBarSDK files weren't imported properly.

To fix this, I deleted them from my project tree (Frameworks folder, next to Supporting Files and Products), then drag and dropped them back in.  Xcode automatically handled everything.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the libraries that the third-party library also depends on.  One is Apple's `ExternalAccessory.framework".  The other seems to be from yet another third-party item called ZBarReaderView.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarReaderView.html

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot!  How did you know what it needed to add, and why on earth doesn't Xcode handle automatic dependency resolution??

Comment: Somebody told me about this thing called "Google".  :)  The three starting with "EA" matched an Apple document and the other came up with the link I posted.

Comment: D'oh!  I was only Googling the undefined symbols error.

Comment: i added `ExternalAccessory.framework` and it's started working :-). thanks.